# Span tag becoming invisible after JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have tried to make a form but am having a problem where the second message in the span tag is disappearing after my JavaScript function is being run once the submit button is being pressed, and only the first message is being displayed.

```js
function formValidate() {
  var fname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
  if (fname == '' || fname == 'null') {
    document.getElementById('fnamemessage').innerHTML = '* Please fill out first name';
    return false;
  }

  var num = document.getElementById('mobilenumber').value;
  if (isNaN(num)) {
    document.getElementById('phonemessage').innerHTML = '* Please only enter numbers';
    return false;
  }
  if (num == '' || num == 'null') {
    document.getElementById('phonemessage').innerHTML = '* Please fill out mobile number';
    return false;
  }
  if (num.length < 11) {
    document.getElementById('phonemessage').innerHTML = '* Mobile number must be more than 10 digits';
    return false;
  }
  if ((num.charAt(0) != 0) && (num.charAt(1) != 7)) {
    document.getElementById('phonemessage').innerHTML = '* Mobile number must start with 07';
    return false;
  }

}
```

```html
<form onsubmit='return formValidate()'>
  First Name: <input type='text' id='firstname' value=''>
  <span id='fnamemessage' class='messages'></span><br></br>
  Mobile Number: <input type='text' id='mobilenumber' value=''>
  <span id='phonemessage' class='messages'></span><br></br>
  <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: Note that `return` will end the function early and none of the following checks are evaluated.

Comment: Thank you very much Patrick, really appreciate the response

Comment: Would you suggest adding another function for validation of each element, ie for first name and for phone number?

Comment: Remember: `null` is not equal to `'null'`. Actually, it is the opposite. `null` means no value. However, if you put it in brackets it will become a string so if I type `null` in each field it won't throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems only the first message appears because the checks for the rest are not reached. You stop execution of the validate function as soon as the first error is reached. You can try to check all errors together as follows:

```
function formValidate() {
    var valid = true;
    var fname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
    if (fname=='' || fname==null) {
        document.getElementById('fnamemessage').innerHTML='* Please fill out first name';
        valid = false;
    }

    var num = document.getElementById('mobilenumber').value;
    if(isNaN(num)) {
        document.getElementById('phonemessage').innerHTML='* Please only enter numbers';
        valid = false;
    }
    if (num=='' || num==null) {
        document.getElementById('phonemessage').innerHTML='* Please fill out mobile number';
        valid = false;
    }
    if (num.length<11) {
        document.getElementById('phonemessage').innerHTML='* Mobile number must be more than 10 digits';
        valid = false;
    }
    if((num.charAt(0)!=0) && (num.charAt(1)!=7)) {
        document.getElementById('phonemessage').innerHTML='* Mobile number must start with 07';
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Comment: Fixed null expression per Aaron's comment

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you `return false` in an if-statement. If you `return` something (in this case `false`) it ends the functions. All other if-statements will NOT be executed. To fix this, just remove `return false` on each if-statement. Since the returned value will not be used you don't even need a return value.

The problem is that (since you don't stop the function and return `false`) the form will be submitted even if your validation rules don't match. In this case, you might want to try something like this:

```js
function formValidate(event) {
  var valid = true;
  var fname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
  if (fname == '') {
    document.getElementById('fnamemessage').innerHTML = '* Please fill out first name';
    valid = false;
  }

  var num = document.getElementById('mobilenumber').value;
  if (isNaN(num)) {
    document.getElementById('phonemessage').innerHTML = '* Please only enter numbers';
    valid = false;
  }
  if (num == '') {
    document.getElementById('phonemessage').innerHTML = '* Please fill out mobile number';
    valid = false;
  }
  if (num.length < 11) {
    document.getElementById('phonemessage').innerHTML = '* Mobile number must be more than 10 digits';
    valid = false;
  }
  if ((num.charAt(0) != 0) && (num.charAt(1) != 7)) {
    document.getElementById('phonemessage').innerHTML = '* Mobile number must start with 07';
    valid = false;
  }


  return valid;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit='return formValidate();'>

  First Name: <input type='text' id='firstname' value=''>
  <span id='fnamemessage' class='messages'></span><br></br>
  Mobile Number: <input type='text' id='mobilenumber' value=''>
  <span id='phonemessage' class='messages'></span><br></br>
  <input type='submit' value='Submit'>

</form>
```

So you at the end you check if your form is valid and end the functions after ALL validations are done.

Comment: Or initialize with `var valid = true;` and at the end `return valid;` instead of having to check its value.

Comment: Also, you forgot something that I didn't fix in my answer. If you got a validation error it shows the error inside the span. However, if there is an error message inside the span already you don't remove it if there is NO validation error. You might want to add an `else` statement which removes the text.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yes that is a better way. I will make an edit real quick. You got my upvote ;)

Comment: @Aaron3219, you still don't initialize the ``var valid;``. You will return undefined here.

Comment: How do i initialize the var valid?

Comment: would beginning the function with valid = true; be okay?

Comment: I edited my answer already (I thought I initialized it with true). @DanielWood you HAVE to initialize it with true. Otherwise, it will always return false.